# Vscode Haskell syntax highlighting color suddenly not working or missing

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, colors, cabal

[image]

My Haskell isn't showing any more syntax highlight and color, but I can still write it with suggestions and snippets. This is the first time it happened, and it works without a problem before, that it shows color and syntax highlighting

I've already tried uninstalling vscode and reinstalling again, installing GHCup again, and restarting my Mac. But still, I can't get the syntax color back. Tried changing the theme too, reinstalling Haskell related extension but nothing works.

Before this happen, I was reopening my vscode, and it pops out some message error on the right bottom, that says: "Error with calling Haskell server 3 times, so not calling again" or something along those lines, because I remember it only vaguely and now it doesn't reappear anymore.

How do I fix this syntax color highlighting issue with Haskell?

Comment: Did you check that you have haskell syntax highlighting extension enabled? This is strange, indeed.

Comment: @Abastro Yes, I did. However, I managed to see the issue, it was the extension with their new update. Now I had to revert to previous version and it worked. https://github.com/JustusAdam/language-haskell/issues/208

Comment: Oh no, why would the extension devs make such a critical mistake. Sad.. Still, glad that it could easily be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [a bug in the language-haskell extension](https://github.com/JustusAdam/language-haskell/issues/208), introduced in 3.5.0. It has been fixed today, with 3.6.0 out.

Comment: I'm still having this issue with 3.6.0 rolling back to 3.3.0 works. Ah, I read that 3.6.0 is broken in the open VSX store. It probably works in the official store.